# Xcode is unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: xcode, image, uiimageview, constraints

When I run the app that I am working on I get a message in the console that says

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you `don't want. 
Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't
expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and
fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you 
don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)`
```

[image: Constraint error in the Xcode debugging console]

All I have is an background image with constraints for `height`, `width`, `trailing space`, `leading space`, `top space`, and `bottom space`. The size of the image is 321 x 571, 641 x 1137, and 960 x 1704.

[image: Constraints for image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you a simple advice: try to remove all constraints and add some of them one step at a time.

...but I suspect that the problem is maybe the `height`, `top space` and `bottom space` to a single image: if your image should have an height can't be at the same time respect bottom and top space in all screens size without any priority set to the constraints. If you are in this case you need to remove one constraint at least of these.

I hope this helps, otherwise add more info to your question.